# VBA script to select data under specific column depending on date

Tags: vba, excel

Currently taken over a new role at work and I'm wanting to make my job a lot easier.

I have three sheets within one workbook.

[Sheet 1 - Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkdSq.png)

[Sheet 2 - Overall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsaIX.png)

[Sheet 3 - This Week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYNfE.png)

What I want to do is depending on the date in sheet 1, I want it to find the corresponding date in the headers on sheet 2, and then select the data in the column and paste it to sheet 3.

For example: If Sheet 1 is 13th May 2018
Sheet 2, D2 - D4 will be copied to Sheet 3 B2 - B4

Is this possible in a macro?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. As this is not a free code-writing service, please post the code you have and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: <begin snark>Yes; it is certainly possible. You could use SQL, constructing the SQL statement with the appropriate column based on the value in the first cell of the first sheet. Please feel free to do so.</end snark>

Comment: If I'm honest, I have no clue where to begin. But thank you for informing me it's possible. I'm sure google will be able to help somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use a formula ?

In Sheet3, range B2 :

`=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A2,0,MATCH(Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$F$1,0)-1)`

You can copy this formula in Sheet3, range B2:B4

Two things to check :

- The format of the date you are looking for.
- The size of the range you are looking up for that date. Column F might not be the last column of your data.